# Vimeo error using embedded video in cordova android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, embed, vimeo

I hope someone can help me get a little transparency on this matter.

I've made an app targeted iOS and Android. The app uses embedded video from Vimeo, via an iframe.

When i run the project on an Android device, the console spits out this error: 
`https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/2.51.2/js/player.js: Line 14 : Uncaught (in promise) AbortError: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

Normally I would say the problem is in the .js, but since it works flawlesly on iOS i actually don't think it's what triggers it.

Comment: Have you solved this problem by now?